con't install .msi in windows

i am getting this alert when i try to install .msi file.. whats wrong?
i am trying to install this https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi
its not just this msi it seems like i have an issue with windows-installer but how this could be fixed, please GUID me
i wana be able to install .msi just like normal

I have had this problem in the past, but chances are, it's for a different reason.  So, I'm going to make a couple of suggestions short of re-installing your OS.
Start off by opening a command prompt as Administrator, and type in the following commands:
msiexec /unregister
msiexec /regserver

Download the following zip file, which contains a .reg.
Windows Installer Registry Defaults
This includes the default registry properties for Windows Installer.  If any of them have changed or have become corrupted, Windows Installer may not work.  Double-click on the .reg to write these values to your registry.  Now reboot and try that AWS .MSI again.
Good luck.  Let us know if it still doesn't work and we can explore some other options.  The two shown here are the most common fixes.
